# Why Mac and Safari not supported UTF-8 letters in C# HttpContent Response?

Tags: c#, safari, amazon-cloudfront, httpcontext

im using AWS cloudfornt in my project. When users with MAC and Safari tried to download files with UTF-8 letters (hebrew for example), It's downloaded without support the real file name. I checked in my code and the url download string return good and if i copied the string and tried download, is work, but if i wait for the response of the HttpContext and then download, is not work.
I tried this but wasn't succeed:

```
context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
context.Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

Any solution to solve it?

Comment: Well, what is the value of `url` here?

Comment: is with expiration, i can't sent. Just said that when i copied the url is work. but from the httpContexts is not work

Comment: @MarcGravell is example - https://file location.jpg?response-content-disposition=attachment%3bfilename%3dBBK35156.jpg&Expires=1686049200&Signature=XXXXXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXX and expect the "BBK35156.jpg" is something like %2%34%

Comment: but... that's a url, not a content-disposition header, and even it it was: a content-disposition header should use `;` - this just looks like malformed http header data?

Comment: @MarcGravell It's an example of the structure URL, I can't pass all the URL as is it.. in Chrome it work for me.. just not in Safari

Comment: Exactly; content-disposition **is not** part of the URL, so the fact that it is in the URL: is probably the problem. If you're doing something with the URL, we need to see the actual final headers: that is what matters here